# How to get the current browser window in the renderer in Electron 14

Tags: typescript, electron

Until now in use the following code to to get the current window from the `renderer`:

```
import {remote, BrowserWindow} from 'electron';

export function getCurrentWindow(): BrowserWindow {
    return remote.getCurrentWindow();
}
```

What is the new recommended way to do this, now that electron 14 has removed the `remote` module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep using the `remote` module, you'll have to now install it from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@electron/remote). `remote` was stripped out (as per [this discussion](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21408)) and is now maintained in a separate userland repo, because the Electron team doesn't want to encourage that pattern, and the npm page says:

> ⚠️ Warning! This module has [many subtle pitfalls](https://nornagon.medium.com/electrons-remote-module-considered-harmful-70d69500f31). There is almost always a better way to accomplish your task than using this module. For example, `ipcRenderer.invoke` can serve many common use cases.

The `npm` page further details how to install and use the `remote` module.

That being said, the recommended strategy is to do all your window operations in the main process and trigger it from the renderer via calls to `ipcRenderer.invoke` or `ipcRenderer.send`.