# Remote still undefined after editing web preferences

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am creating a electron app and came across this problem:

I have a nice landing page. Now I want to switch between the html pages. As usual, index.js is in root directory and the html and javascript files in src/ directory.

I found a solution where the user had answered to set the "enableRemoteModule" to true. So eventually I did but still, when i did:

```
const electron = require('electron')

console.log(electron.remote) // Gave undefined
```

Is this the problem new or there is some problem with my own project code?

Browser code:

```
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()

const { BrowserWindow } = require('@electron/remote')

let mainWindow

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 700,
    height: 600,
    hasShadow: true,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        enableRemoteModule: true,
    },
});

mainWindow.on('closed', _ => {
    console.log('closed')
    mainWindow = null
})

mainWindow.loadFile("src/html/welcome.html")
```

New code after reading the comment. However, a new error:

`Error: "@electron/remote" cannot be required in the browser process. Instead require("@electron/remote/main").`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current browser window in the renderer in Electron 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69070320/how-to-get-the-current-browser-window-in-the-renderer-in-electron-14)

Comment: if you're on electron 14, the remote module was removed entirely. See the link above

Comment: Yeah, i am current using v14.0.1

Comment: Well, i link that you have provided, I saw and read them. However, there is a new issue arising. Gonna edit the question.

Comment: remote is intended to be used in renderer processes, not the main process. In this case, you shoudl just be requiring browserwindow from "electron" Second, you'll need to enable the remote for the specific webcontents you want to use it in `require("@electron/remote/main").enable(webContents)`