# Electron getFocusedWindow().close() not working

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm having trouble with electron when making a custom title bar.

When clicking the button in the below code, the window should ideally close, which it doesn't seem to.

```js
document.getElementById("close-btn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const {
        remote
    } = require('electron');
    remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().close();
});
```

```html
<div id="title-bar">
    <div id="title">My App</div>
    <div id="title-bar-btns">
        <button id="min-btn">-</button>
        <button id="max-btn">[]</button>
        <button id="close-btn">x</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you sure that you don't get any error message in Electron's DevTools? Try opening them like in Chrome with `[Ctrl]`+`[Shift]`+`[I]`, look for an error in the console, [edit] your question and include the stacktrace please! Thanks!

Comment: could be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69070320/how-to-get-the-current-browser-window-in-the-renderer-in-electron-14/69092438#69092438)

Comment: thank you pushkin, now im using ipcrenderer and it works fine, also thanks to  alexander for giving me a welcome and remember me that i have to use the devtools(i didn't remember)