# How to access command line arguments from renderer process now remote is deprecated

Tags: electron

I currently access command line arguments to my Electron-based application via the remote module:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const parseArgs = require('minimist');
let args = parseArgs(electron.remote.process.argv.slice(2));
```

Electron 11 has now reached end of life and from Electron 12 the remote module is [deprecated](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21408).

I understand that it's possible to use remote via the [@electron/remote](https://github.com/electron/remote) package, but that repo warns that "There is almost always a better way to accomplish your task than using this module."

What's the recommended way for accessing command line arguments from the renderer process without using the remote module?

Comment: you just use ipc. It's mentioned in the github post (e.g. [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21408#issuecomment-564184702))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current browser window in the renderer in Electron 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69070320/how-to-get-the-current-browser-window-in-the-renderer-in-electron-14)

Comment: Thanks pushkin, I was able to solve this with ipcMain.handle() and ipcRenderer.invoke().