# I want close electron app from another html page with button

Tags: javascript, html, electron

We are currently improve a project with electronjs:  We have main.js for electron as you know and we have another html page that javascripts codes in it. We created a close button in this html page and this button should close the app but we cant reach main.js for close the app. Can you help me?

This code is from html page :

```
<div class="background-three link-container">
        <button class="link-three" onclick="kapat()" id="kptbtn">Kapat</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        function kapat(){
            //what should I write here.
        }
    </script>
```

and this main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')




function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
    resizable: false,
    width: 500,
    height: 700,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('girisEkrani.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

Comment: *but we cant reach main.js for close the app. Can you help me?* wouldnt this functionality requirement defeat the purpose of "cross-platform"?

Comment: I dont think like that. This function a basic close function just reach main.js for the solution.

Comment: I have been searching last few days and I found something like electron remote and ipcMain or ipcRenderer but I cant solve

Comment: somewhat [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69070320/how-to-get-the-current-browser-window-in-the-renderer-in-electron-14/69092438#69092438). You'll need to create a preload script and have it use ipcRenderer to send a message to the main process that closes the window. I am pretty sure there are dupes of this question here somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer`. Main for reading message and Renderer for sending message.

> .html page

```
<script>
    function kapat() {
        const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
        const ipc = ipcRenderer;
        ipc.send('kapat');
    }
    ...
</script>
```

if you define ipc stuff out of the function it will not work and effect other functions.

> main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const ipc = ipcMain;

function createWindow() {
const win = new BrowserWindow({
transparent: true,
frame: false,
resizable: false,
width: 500,
height: 700,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    contextIsolation: false,
  }
})

ipc.on('kapat', () => { win.close() })
win.loadFile('girisEkrani.html')
}
```