# 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined' in Electron 19.0.6

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to load a new file into my Electron application but I get the following error:
[image: The error I get]

This is my code:

```js
    document.getElementById('settings').addEventListener('click', () => {
      remote.getFocusedWindow().loadFile('/settings/settings.html')
    });
```

I have nodeIntegration **enabled** in my main.js
Thank you for helping ^^

Comment: did you disable contextisolation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron nodeIntegration not working, also general weird Electron behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506331/electron-nodeintegration-not-working-also-general-weird-electron-behavior)

Comment: as far as using `remote` goes, you might have issues. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69070320/how-to-get-the-current-browser-window-in-the-renderer-in-electron-14/69092438#69092438)